# column width - beginner python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on this quick project to learn and I semi-successfully finished printing each list into a column but I'm having troubles printing the correct column width.

```
fruitNamePets = [   ['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'bananas', 'pineapples', 'mangos'],
                    ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David', 'Mike', 'Alex'],
                    ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose', 'deer', 'platypus']
                ]

def printTable(tableName):
    colWidths = [0] * len(tableName)                
    for i in range(len(tableName[1])):  
        print ('')          
        for j in range(len(tableName)):             
            colWidths[j] = len(max(tableName[j])) + 2
            print (str(tableName[j][i]).rjust(colWidths[j], ' '), end='')   

printTable(fruitNamePets)
```

Here is the output

```
      apples Alice      dogs
     oranges   Bob      cats
    cherries Carol     moose
     bananas David     goose
  pineapples  Mike      deer
      mangos  Alex  platypus
```

As you can see, **I right justified the columns and made the width the largest length of the list +2 spaces, except for some reason the middle column is only adding +1 space.**

Thanks for your help, I'm new here so if I'm posting incorrectly please let me know!

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but the Python `.format` method handles quite a lot of these things natively: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language (see the `align` parameters in particular); that may make your life much easier for aligning things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
colWidths[j] = len(max(tableName[j])) + 2
```

`max(tableName[j])` returns you the "biggest" value in `tableName[j]`. In the case of a list of strings, this means the one that sorts the highest alphabetically. So "pineapples" in the first column, "Mike" in the second, and "platypus" in the third. Then you're using the length of that word.

What you really want is the length of the *longest* word. Try this instead:

```
colWidths[j] = max(len(word) for word in tableName[j]) + 2
```

`len(word) for word in tableName[j]` is a "list comprehension" that turns a list of strings into a list of lengths of strings. List comprehension is a great part of the Python language, so if you haven't seen it already, this is a great time to learn it!

**EDIT**

Here's a "by-hand" version of what the list comprehension is doing:

```
lengths = []
for word in tableName[j]:
    lengths.append(len(word))
colWidths[j] = max(lengths) + 2
```

We're collecting all the lengths of the strings, then finding the max of those lengths.

Comment: Hey thanks I appreciate the detailed answer! 

I actually did not know how to find the longest word in the list so I googled a way and erroneously used max.

Comment: or you could do `len(max(tableName[j], key=len)) + 2`....but has two many len's anyway :)